# How to delete temp files using python?

Tags: python

So I tried to create a script that deletes all of your downloaded files and temp files. It deletes the downloaded files, but for the temp files I'm getting an error.

```
import os
import shutil

temp_dir = "C:\Windows\Temp"
downloads_dir = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], "Downloads")

quit = input("Do you want to delete all the downloads? (Press enter to continue)")

for file in os.listdir(downloads_dir):
    file_path = os.path.join(downloads_dir, file)
    if os.path.isdir(file_path):
        shutil.rmtree(file_path)
    else:
        os.remove(file_path)

print("All the downloaded files were deleted.")

quit = input("Do you want to delete all the temp files? (Press enter to continue)")

for file in os.listdir(temp_dir):
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, file)
    if os.path.isdir(file_path):
        shutil.rmtree(file_path)
    else:
        os.remove(file_path)
        
print("All the temp files were deleted.")
```

This is the code. After running it, the downloaded files are deleted but at the temp files I get this error:

```
os.remove(file_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\DESKTOP-0CR5QUA-20221230-0000.log'
```

Comment: what unclear is in error message you are seeing?

Comment: Use the `tempfile` module and let *it* delete the file for you.

Comment: Don't forget to use raw strings when a path contains backslashes.

Comment: the `tmp` dir is used by process to create temporary  files, if files in tmp dir is used by any process you can't delete it

Comment: @chepner I thought so, but the script isn't actually creating the temp files itself. It's a directory being used by other applications.

Comment: This temp directory is used by many applications on the system, you should be deleting random files from it.

Comment: Temp files should be cleaned up by the process that creates them; how do you know the other process isn't actually still using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If other processes are currently using the temporary files in `C:\Windows\Temp` you'll get an error, because deleting currently used files could cause errors in those other processes.

If you get a `PermissionError` when you try to do this, just wrap it in a try/except so that it can continue deleting the rest of the files that aren't being used instead of crashing the program.

Also know that deleting temp files, even if they aren't currently opened by another process, could still be looked up, so that might cause issues.

```py
for file in os.listdir(temp_dir):
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, file)
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(file_path):
            shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        else:
            os.remove(file_path)
    except PermissionError:
        pass
```